# How to deserialize a JSON Properties containing numbers using POCO class?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, poco

I was practising JSON Deserialization using JSONUtility in Unity engine.I solved some examples using POCO class when the properties were string with help of stackoverflow([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882500/argumentoutofrangeexceptioncant-figure-out-error-while-working-with-poco-class?noredirect=1#comment94637268_53882500)).I have solved the following JSON.[Link](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfmxqecgky?indent=2) using the exact names in the POCO class.But when the JSON properties contains integers like the following .

```
{


"1": {
    "Armor": 1, 
    "Strenght": 1
  }, 
  "0": {
    "Armor": 1, 
    "Mana": 2, 
    "Strenght": 1, 
    "Health": 1, 
    "Power": 1
  }
}
```

Solving in a similar way did not work out.From the feedback I got,I have to use dictionary.

```
 IEnumerator GetExampleValues()
{
    string URLss = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOQGnptixu?indent=2";
    WWW readjson = new WWW(URLss);
    yield return readjson;

    Debug.Log("ReadJSON"+readjson.text);


}
```

My POCO class below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class Exampleget  
{
    public int Power;
    public int Mana;
    public int Strenght;
    public int Armor;
    public int Health;

}

public class GetNumbers
{

    public List<Exampleget> onevalues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be using JsonExtensionData Attribute

```
public class Exampleget  
{
    public int Power;
    public int Mana;
    public int Strenght;
    public int Armor;
    public int Health;

}

public class GetNumbers
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string,dynamic> Values;
}
```

With the Class in place, now you could,

```
var str = @"{
        '1': {
            'Armor': 1, 
            'Strenght': 1
          }, 
          '0': {
            'Armor': 1, 
            'Mana': 2, 
            'Strenght': 1, 
            'Health': 1, 
            'Power': 1
          }
        }";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetNumbers>(str);
foreach(var item in result.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"For Key {item.Key},Power = {item.Value.Power}, Mana = {item.Value.Mana}, Armor = {item.Value.Armor}, Health = {item.Value.Health}");
}
```

Output

```
For Key 1,Power = , Mana = , Armor = 1, Health = 
For Key 0,Power = 1, Mana = 2, Armor = 1, Health = 1
```

**Update**

In case you want to have the Dictionary as `Dictionary<string,Exampleget>` instead of using dynamic, then you can make use of an additional property which does conversion to Exampleget. But this comes at a cost of additional serialization/deserialization, hence wouldn't recommend unless you have good reasons to stick to it.

```
public class GetNumbers
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string,object> Values;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string,Exampleget> ExamplegetDictionary=> Values.Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<string,Exampleget>(x.Key, ((object)x.Value).Cast<Exampleget>()))
                                                                      .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,y=>y.Value);

}

public static class Extension
{
    public static T Cast<T>(this object value)
    {
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to add any plugins..I was using JsonUtility for unity.I was trying to solve using Jsonutility.What is ' T ' Cast<T> ..I did not understand that...Please chk......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882500/argumentoutofrangeexceptioncant-figure-out-error-while-working-with-poco-class?noredirect=1#comment94707010_53882500

Comment: The above code Newtonsoft.Json for deserialization. The Cast<T> method is used to cast a dynamic object to T(in this case, Exampleget).